# Updating a range of cells based on the value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm extremely new, so please bear with me.  I want to evaluate each cell in the range C5:BM5.  If any of the cells in that range = "HOLIDAY" or "SUN" I need to have rows 7-19 in that column cleared.  I've cobbled together the code below, which does what I need it to, it just does it very slowly.  I know there has to be a better way.  Looking for some clever advice.

```
Sub HolidayUpdate()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Sheets("Production Calendar").Range("C5:BM5")

If Cell = "HOLIDAY" Then
Cell.Offset(2, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(3, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(4, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(5, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(6, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(7, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(8, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(9, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(10, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(11, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(12, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(13, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(14, 0).ClearContents
ElseIf Cell = "SUN" Then
Cell.Offset(2, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(3, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(4, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(5, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(6, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(7, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(8, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(9, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(10, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(11, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(12, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(13, 0).ClearContents
Cell.Offset(14, 0).ClearContents
End If

Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you can combine all your offsets.
2. you can disable calculation and screen updating.
3. Here's the update for your code.

   ```
   Sub HolidayUpdate()

   Dim rgCell As Range

   application.screenupdating=false
   application.calculation=xlcalculationmanual

   For Each rgCell In Sheets("Production Calendar").Range("C5:BM5")

       If rgCell = "HOLIDAY" OR rgCell = "SUN" _
           Then rgCell.Offset(2, 0).resize(13).ClearContents

   Next rgCell 

   application.screenupdating=true
   application.calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: In addition you could use 1 if statement:  If rgCell = "HOLIDAY" OR rgCell = "SUN" then

Comment: there's a typo in the last line, should read xlcalculatioNautomatic